# Font Viewer not running in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, fonts

Anybody else having an issue with Font Viewer not running? It just shows the mouse busy cursor spinning, but eventually does nothing? Is there a fix?﻿

Comment: @Rinzwind, no errors when running "gnome-font-viewer" from terminal.

Comment: please add yourself to the "affected" people :) (see the "reported" link in my answer)

Comment: Added myself to the list of affected users. :) Thanks.

Comment: Nominated this question for reopening. Basically it doesn't matter any longer, since the issue has been fixed in the archive now, but for a few weeks the workarounds have been useful for the users. My point is that when answers provide useful workarounds, questions shouldn't be considered off topic only because the root cause is a bug.

Answer (score 25):

I edited the `.desktop` file as a workaround:

```
sudo sed -ir 's/^\(DBus\)/#\1/' /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop
```

Normally I advise against changing package owned file under `/usr/share`, since such changes will be overridden at next update of the package in question. However, in this case the issue is about to be [fixed with the next update of the package](http://launchpad.net/bugs/1607937), and it will start working again without workarounds.

The fix for this has been released, please run

`sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Confirmed by the way: this fixes it.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  DBusActivatable=true was commented out. Nice find on the root cause.

Comment: @ElderGeek: Not really the root cause, I think. The yakkety version of gnome-font-viewer works fine with that line. I'm about to check out if a rebuild of the source may be sufficient to fix it: https://launchpad.net/~gunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/font-viewer

Comment: I'm pretty sure the broken launcher file was the root cause otherwise creating a new desktop shortcut as I did in the second part of my answer would not have fixed it.

Comment: @ElderGeek: It merely confirms that the workaround works. ;) Anyway, I have [proposed that the yakkety version is backported to xenial](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1607937). Let's see what the developers think about that.

Comment: Perhaps I 'm slow. Can you explain to me why if the program was faulty either my approach to creating a new launcher or your approach of editing the existing launcher would work?

Comment: @ElderGeek: To be honest I don't know why it works. OTOH the yakkety version works fine without any workaround, and it also includes the "DBusActivatable=true" line in the .desktop file. That's why I don't think that the root cause lies in the .desktop file.

Comment: That's definitely odd. change in dbus handling perhaps?

Comment: @ElderGeek: This is the root fix upstream: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-font-viewer/commit/?id=acf919c

Comment: This works for me as well

Comment: @AziBaloch: Actually it shouldn't be needed any longer on an updated 16.04.

Comment: I'm already running on 16.04 BTW today i was trying to open a font than i realized that my font viewer is not working :(  i applied your solution and it worked for me :) .

Comment: @AziBaloch: Ok, great, but in that case you have probably not updated the packages for a while. You can install the latest version of the Xenial packages with: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Answer (score 7):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Issue the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
gnome-font-viewer --display=:0
```

As an alternative you could create a desktop shortcut for it.

One way to do this is to use the old gnome-desktop-item-edit.

First you'll need to install is with `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`

Next issue the command `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop

Fill out the fields as shown:

[image: fontviewershorcut]

It worked for me.

Source: Experience

Answer (score 4):

There is an error showing up in `/var/log/syslog`.

```
Jul 29 22:07:21 schijfwereld org.gnome.font-viewer[3361]: 
Unknown option --gapplication-service
Jul 29 22:07:21 schijfwereld org.gnome.font-viewer[3361]: 
Run '/usr/bin/gnome-font-viewer --help' 
to see a full list of available command line options.
```

[I did not find a bug reported on this on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-font-viewer).

It only happens when starting it from "dash" not when started from command line. So use that for the time being.

---

[Reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-font-viewer/+bug/1607937).

Comment: Actually it was reported a couple of days ago: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1606743

Comment: Ah damn. I searched for the option and got 0 hits :* I suck at searching it sems.

Answer (score 1):

I am  not sure why it does not work on a longterm release..(Gnome 16.04.1) 
However, this led me to discover font-manager

```
sudo apt install font-manager
```

It took a long long time to load when I started it, but it eventually worked and then was no problem subsequently.  To install fonts, you can click rightmost icon on the lower icon row and dump a whole directory all at once (using CTRL+A).  It is a little slow, but it is sort of like a washing machine..dump the stuff inside and then come back later.  Awesome.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Got this bug while installing [Symbol font](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IamDH4/ttf-wps-fonts/master/symbol.ttf).

Seems to be reported [to LaunchPad as bug 1717678](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-font-viewer/+bug/1717678).

For myself I fixed this bug by installing font from MATE Font Viewer (part of `mate-control-center` package).

MATE rocks again.